# RecyclerView не работает в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-asynctask

Я сделал приложение-парсер, которое должно выводить все данные в `recyclerview` во фрагменте, и сперва протестировал его в отдельной активности. Всё работало, но когда я реализовал это через фрагмент - всё перестало работать(просто выводит белый экран и всё). Что делать? Код прилагаю ниже:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            NewsParserFragment fragment = new NewsParserFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.placeholder, fragment).commit();
        }

    }

}
```

NewsParserFragment

```
public class NewsParserFragment extends Fragment {

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    public Elements content;

    public ArrayList<NewsElement> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<NewsElement> savedNewsList = new ArrayList<>();


    public NewsParserFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_parser, container, false);

        NewThread newThread = new NewThread();
        newThread.execute();
        Log.d("Parser", "Запуск потока");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(view.getContext(), newsList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_parser, container, false);
    }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String cleaner(String a){
            String source = a;
            String result = "";
            ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
            arr.add(source);

            for(String retrival: source.split(" ")){
                arr.add(retrival);

            }
            arr.remove(0);
            Iterator<String> iterator = arr.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String string = iterator.next();
                if (string.equals("Россия") || string.equals("Екатеринбург")) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }else{
                    result += string+" ";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        String url_interpretator(String src){
            String result="";
            String interval = "";

            char[] morph = src.toCharArray();
            morph[0]=' ';
            morph[1]=' ';

            for (char a : morph){
                if(a==' '){
                    continue;
                }else{
                    interval=interval+a;
                }
            }

            result="https://"+interval;

            return result;
        }
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        protected  String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            Document doc;
            String  newsText,  newsDate,  newsTime,  newsPicURL,  newsLink;

            try{
                doc= Jsoup.connect("https://www.znak.com/?&%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5").get();
                content = doc.select(".pub");

                int link_counter = 0;

                newsList.clear();
                for(Element contents: content){


                    String linkID = doc.getElementsByClass("pub").get(link_counter).attr("href");

                    String region = doc.getElementsByClass("region").get(link_counter).text();

                    String time = doc.getElementsByTag("time").get(link_counter).attr("datetime");

                    String sourceYear;



                    DateAndTime dat = new DateAndTime(time);
                    newsText=cleaner(contents.text());
                    newsDate=" "+dat.getYear()+" ";
                    newsTime=dat.getTime();


                    Document doc2 = null;
                    try {
                        doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.znak.com" + linkID).get();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String pic_url = url_interpretator(doc2.getElementsByTag("img").get(1).attr("src"));
                    String readyURL = pic_url;
                    Log.d("picture", contents.text() + " " + pic_url);
                    newsPicURL=readyURL;

                    sourceYear=dat.getSourceYear();
                    newsLink="https://znak.com"+linkID;
                    NewsElement newsElement = new NewsElement( newsText,  newsDate,  newsTime,  newsPicURL,  newsLink, sourceYear);
                    newsList.add(newsElement);

                    Comparator<NewsElement> comparator = new Comparator<NewsElement>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(NewsElement o1, NewsElement o2) {
                            Log.d("Comparator", o1.getNewsDate());
                            return -(o1.getSourceYear().compareTo(o2.getSourceYear()));
                        }
                    };

                    newsList.sort(comparator);


                    publishProgress();
                    link_counter++;
                }

            }catch (IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class DateAndTime{


        private String date;
        private String sourceYear;
        private String year;
        private String time="";
        private char[] timeArr;

        DateAndTime(String date){
            this.date=date;
        }

        public String getSourceYear() {
            return sourceYear;
        }

        String getYear(){


            String[] dateAndTime = date.split("T");
            String[] dateArr = dateAndTime[0].split("-");

            timeArr = dateAndTime[1].toCharArray();
            year = dateArr[2]+"."+dateArr[1]+"."+dateArr[0];
            sourceYear = dateArr[0]+"."+dateArr[1]+"."+dateArr[2];

            return year;

        }


        String getTime(){

            for(int i = 0; i<timeArr.length-4; i++){
                time=time+timeArr[i];
            }

            String intTime = String.valueOf(timeArr[0])+String.valueOf(timeArr[1]);
            int timeValue = Integer.valueOf(intTime)+5;

            if(timeValue>23){
                timeValue=timeValue-24;
                String time = "0"+String.valueOf(timeValue)+timeArr[2]+timeArr[3]+timeArr[4];
                return time;
            }else{
                String time = String.valueOf(timeValue)+timeArr[2]+timeArr[3]+timeArr[4];
                return time;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не то возвращаете из `onCreateView`. Вместо

`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_parser, container, false);`

которое делает бессмысленными все вышележащие действия вам надо вернуть из метода сформированную ранее и инициализированную переменную `view`:

`return view;`